# How to get limited digits in uuid python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I want only 10 digit unique integer number. How can I do that? Please help me.

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().int
```

**Output**

```
155824466611029597996750071195809352096
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try**

```
import uuid
str(uuid.uuid4().int)[:10]
```

A better idea would be to generate a cryptographic token with the desired length. This also has the possibility of collisions, but I imagine it would be much less than a truncated UUID.

**Other Solution**

[shortuuid](https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/)

Comment: I think unique. But honestly it's not a good solution.

Comment: Yes, it is unique, _but_ because you're throwing away bytes from the original UUID, it therefore becomes more likely that Python's UUID generator might generate the same value twice.

Comment: @BB_Mevada. A better idea would be to generate a cryptographic token with the desired length. This also has the possibility of collisions, but I imagine it would be much less than a truncated UUID.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So is there any other solution?

Comment: @BB_Mevada [shortuuid](https://pypi.org/project/shortuuid/)

Comment: @SuperStar Thanks :) That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

`int` has no `subscriptable` object. So try to convert it into `str` then slice it

```
import uuid
x = str(uuid.uuid4().int)
print(x[:10])
```

You can also use the `hex` value

```
uuid.uuid4().hex[:10]
```